# "Four years on" vs. "four years later"

Tags: difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning and usage between *four years on* and *four years later* meaning after four years passed. For example:

> In 2014, she started university, and **four years on**/**four years later** she graduated with a bachelor's degree.

Comment: The subtle difference that I understand between the two is when we say "four years on" we usually mean that something has been in a continuous state for those four years, whereas "four years later" would be better suited after a certain event took place and changes may have happened. Either one works for the example, but "on" leads me to expect she remained in university throughout the four years.

Comment: The difference, if it exists, must be very small. I would use them as equivalent.

Comment: One difference is that Americans don’t use “on” that way. So if your writing for an American audience, use “later”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtle difference that I understand between the two is when we say "four years on" we usually mean that something has been in a continuous state for those four years, whereas "four years later" would be better suited after a certain event took place and changes may have happened. Either one works for the example, but "on" leads me to expect she remained in university throughout the four years.

One difference is that Americans don’t use “on” that way. So if your writing for an American audience, use “later”

Comment: My comment about "the subtle difference" was mostly just my initial reaction and opinion without a source to back it up. Also I disagree with the opinion that Americans don't use "years on", and so does the dictionary.  So I provided a complete answer with references.

Answer (score 3):

To say "four years later" is very clear to all English speakers. Any cause of confusion would come from the word "on" if you use "four years on". So here are the appropriate definitions for the word "on" used there.

---

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on):

> **ON (adverb)**
> **2a:** forward or at a more advanced point in space or time
> *went on home
>
> later on*
> **2 b:** in continuance or succession
> *rambled on*
> *and so on*

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on):

> **ON** *adverb* (Moving Forward)
> **B2 continuing forward in time or space:**
> *They never spoke to each other from that day on (= after that day).
>
> What are you doing later on?
>
> When you're done with it, would you pass it on to Paul?
>
> UK Move on, please, and let the ambulance through.
>
> UK You cycle on and I'll meet you there.*

Notice that both dictionaries recognize the element of **continuation**. Usually, it means that something has happened and will continue to happen when we use "on" this way. But it could also be used to simply mean later in time without a continuous action.

---

Here are some examples of it in use:

> [Arab News Article](https://www.arabnews.com/node/1719506/middle-east):
> "15 years on from Israeli withdrawal, Gazans frustrated by lack of progress"

This simply means "15 years after the withdrawal" without a continuous action.

> [Magnum Photos Article](https://www.magnumphotos.com/newsroom/war-lingers-srebrenica-25-years-on-paolo-pellegrin/):
> "War Lingers: Srebrenica 25 years on"

The word "lingers" and the choice of "on" both tell us that war has continued for 25 years.

> [New York Times Article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/21/opinion/sunday/coronavirus-hurricane-katrina-anniversary.html?searchResultPosition=1):
> "Remembering Katrina and Its Unlearned Lessons, 15 Years On"

I include this to point out that it is not a UK/USA difference. Being American myself, I am very familiar with this use of "on". It is simply less commonly used.